# PHP Split CSV file and update to Database doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, split

I would like to split a very large CSV file (20 000 lines) to be able to put everything in my MySQL database (after I use cronjob for load the php file every hours).

So I have found code to split my file :

```
$inputFile = 'Shipping.csv';
$outputFile = 'output';

$splitSize = 1000;

$in = fopen($inputFile, 'r');

$rowCount = 0;
$fileCount = 1;
while (!feof($in)) {
    if (($rowCount % $splitSize) == 0) {
        if ($rowCount > 0) {
            fclose($out);
        }
        $out = fopen($outputFile . $fileCount++ . '.csv', 'w');
    }
    $data = fgetcsv($in);
    if ($data)
        fputcsv($out, $data);
    $rowCount++;
}

fclose($out);
```

I have tried to do this but they don't work :

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/pdo.php';

$inputFile = 'Shipping.csv';
$outputFile = 'output';

$splitSize = 1000;

//open uploaded csv file with read only mode
$in = fopen($inputFile, 'r');

//skip first line
fgetcsv($in);

$rowCount = 0;
$fileCount = 1;
while (!feof($in)) {
    if (($rowCount % $splitSize) == 0) {
        if ($rowCount > 0) {
            fclose($out);
        }
        $out = fopen($outputFile . $fileCount++ . '.csv', 'w');
    }
    $data = fgetcsv($in);

    if ($data){
        fputcsv($out, $data);
    }


    while(($line = fgetcsv($out)) !== FALSE){
        //check whether member already exists in database with same email
        $prevQuery = "SELECT id FROM shipbp WHERE license = '".$line[1]."'";
        $prevResult = $bdd->query($prevQuery);
        if($prevResult->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $bdd->query("UPDATE shipbp SET license = '".$line[0]."'");
        }
        else{
            $bdd->query("INSERT INTO shipbp (license) VALUES ('".$line[0]."')");
        }
    }

    $rowCount++;
}

fclose($out);
```

CSV file look like :

```
P135460,002,00003,250,AS44563,0.35,,Blabla,17/3/2017 00:00:00,SB,Blabla
```

How I can do ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: any error messages? your update query will update every shipbp row in the database

Comment: The csv is split correctly
But I have no data that goes in my database
And no error messages

Comment: Since you know how to get data from a csv via `fgetcsv`, why not open and read line by line and write it directly into the database in one loop?

Comment: Also make `license` an unique filed and use `INSERT IGNORE INTO`, no splitting and no testing needed.

Comment: By the way: Wy are you using `$line[1]` for select, but `$line[0]` for insert/update.  very unclear

Comment: You can simplify your code by using **INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** if _license_ has  unique index.

Comment: Thank you, I have change this for test code :     `if ($data){
        $bdd->query("INSERT INTO shipbp (license) VALUES ('".$data[0]."')");
        fputcsv($out, $data);
    }` it's works but I still have the error **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded** so I  think what I have done is useless :(